# Upload image on server using PHP in TinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, editor

I am working on TinyMCE text editor with upload image using PHP and JS database but I am confused to send the image on the server -

JS code -

```
<script src='//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.2/tinymce.min.js'></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    theme: "modern",
    paste_data_images: true,
    plugins: [
      "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
      "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
      "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
      "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
    ],
    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
    image_advtab: true,
    file_picker_callback: function(callback, value, meta) {
      if (meta.filetype == 'image') {
        $('#upload').trigger('click');
        $('#upload').on('change', function() {
          var file = this.files[0];
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function(e) {
            callback(e.target.result, {
              alt: ''
            });
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });
      }
    },
    templates: [{
      title: 'Test template 1',
      content: 'Test 1'
    }, {
      title: 'Test template 2',
      content: 'Test 2'
    }]
  });
});
  </script>
```

Image is not showing - 
The showing text -

`<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4QCyRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABwESAAMAAAABAAEAAAE+AAUAAAACAAAAYgE/AAUAAAAGAAAAcgMBAAUAAAABAAAAolEQAAEAAAABAQAAAFERAAQAAAABAAAOxFESAAQAAAABAAAOxAAAAAAAAHolAAGGoAAAgIMAAYagAAD5/wABhqAAAIDpAAGGoAAAdTAAAYagAADqYAABhqAAADqYAAGGoAAAF28AAYagAAGGoA`

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esEVP.png)

HTML  -

How to upload image and display on the page using PHP  -

I tried this example - https://codepen.io/nirajmchauhan/pen/EjQLpV

How to upload an image on the server and retrieve with the image blob link

Comment: How did you put in the image? dragged it in?

Comment: I uploaded the image. I tried this one -  https://codepen.io/nirajmchauhan/pen/EjQLpV

Answer (score 0):

<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4QCyRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABwESAAMAAAABAAEAAAE+AAUAAAACAAAAYgE/AAUAAAAGAAAAcgMBAAUAAAABAAAAolEQAAEAAAABAQAAAFERAAQAAAABAAAOxFESAAQAAAABAAAOxAAAAAAAAHolAAGGoAAAgIMAAYagAAD5/wABhqAAAIDpAAGGoAAAdTAAAYagAADqYAABhqAAADqYAAGGoAAAF28AAYagAAGGoA

SOLUTION: please use database field type LONGTXT after change you can see image in your text editor

Comment: I think there might be an answer according to [answer] hidden in there.... Try using https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help by [edit]ing your post. Then, just for funsies, please take the [tour].